# Como acceder al valor que esta dentro de un array y un objeto?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo quiero acceder al valor 'Elizabeth' para poder imprimirlo en la consola. 
Necesito recorrerlo con un `forEach` cuanndo hay más de un objeto
El array es el siguiente:

```
const informacion = {results: Array(1), info: {…}}
info: {seed: "e8b9382c1cb6324f", results: 1, page: 1, version: "1.3"}
results: Array(1)
0:
cell: "(935)-589-1177"
dob: {date: "1963-03-19T05:27:41.170Z", age: 57}
email: "elizabeth.hart@example.com"
gender: "female"
id: {name: "SSN", value: "288-38-3648"}
location: {street: {…}, city: "Minneapolis", state: "Kentucky", country: "United States", postcode: 18529, …}
login: {uuid: "52e2a851-4cf4-4dc8-98e8-65aade7e1f39", username: "whiteleopard488", password: "kingdom", salt: "sX8q1VGL", md5: "f2acbf4465f3a8a0b248e175e57df6e5", …}
name:
first: "Elizabeth"
last: "Hart"
title: "Miss"
__proto__: Object
nat: "US"
phone: "(884)-809-2690"
picture: {large: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/63.jpg", medium: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/63.jpg", thumbnail: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/63.jpg"}
registered: {date: "2013-05-02T20:48:40.845Z", age: 7}
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: El objeto está en la posición cero del array: `console.log(informacion[0].name.first);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo tiene un objeto puedes imprimirlo con `console.log(informacion[0].name.first)`. Si son varios objetos a los que deseas acceder puedes hacerlo recorriendo el Array:

```
for(let i = 0; i < informacion.lenght; i++){
    console.log(informacion[i].name.first);
}
```

usando [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) quedaría así:

```
informacion.forEach(i => console.log(i.name.first));
```

Comment: Y si debo hacerlo con un forEach ?

Comment: Con el `forEach()` quedaría `informacion.forEach(i => console.log(i.name.first))`.

Comment: Como bien dice @StevenPardo de esa forma quedaria. Ahora te actualizo la respuesta